# Hive + Pass previous day date to like clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

Am trying to fetch records from hive table based on the previous date.
Example: If table is as follows

**CustomerVisit** table

```
ID NAME VISIT_DATE
------------------

01 Harish 2018-02-31

03 Satish 2017-02-13

04 Shiva  2018-03-04
```

Now i need to fetch all records that have `visit_date = 2018-03-04` (i.e today's date -1).

> Expected Query something like:

```
select ID, Name from CustomerVisit where 
visit_date like concat((select date_sub(current_date, 1)),'%')
```

I have tried following

```
select current_date; - Gives current date

select date_sub(current_date, 1) - Gives previous date

select concat(tab1.date1,'%') from 
(select date_sub(current_date, 1) as date1) as tab1; -- Gives the previous date appended with % which i need to use in like
```

but when i use the above as sub-query like below it fails with

```
select tab2.id, (select concat(tab1.date1,'%') as pattern from 
(select date_sub(current_date, 1) as date1) as tab1) from CustomerVisit as tab2 limit 1;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'seelct' 'current_date' ''

How to write query to get results for previous date?

Comment: What is the datatype of `visit_date` ? You don't need to use `LIKE` for date datatypes. simply use `where VISIT_DATE = yesterdays_date`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `LIKE` clause. Just select using an equal to (`=`)

```
select ID, Name from CustomerVisit where 
visit_date = date_sub(current_date, 1);
```